# Credit Card Payment using PayPal - Unable to process error

Tags: paypal

I've integrated PayPal in my application. When I tried payments using credit card, I am getting error as in the image.

[image]

Also, I'm receiving an SMS as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is only relevant to the credit card issue instead of integration problem. Please make sure your card can be used online for international trading and if there is enough balance in this card to make online payments through PayPal. The $1.00 USD in your screenshot is pre-authorization fee. It will back to your card within 30 days because it is not for the real charge but just for the pre-authorization fee.

Comment: Thank you Steven for your reply!